# Appending Expressions to Create Expression of Different Type

Tags: c#, expression

I have a method that receives an `Expression<Func<MyObject, object>>` that I would like to extend by calling a method on the `object`. The result of the extended expression will always be a `bool`. Essentially I want to "convert" `Expression<Func<MyObject, object>>` to `Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>`.

Here is the gist of what I'd like to do. I realize this does not compile as `ReportExpr` is of type `Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>`, not `MethodCallExpression`, but I think this conveys the intent:

```
private MyObjectData CreateMyObjectData(string description, 
    FieldTypes fieldType, Expression<Func<MyObject, object>> expression)
{
    var data= new MyObjectData()
    {
        ReportDesc = description,
        FieldType = fieldType,
    };

    var method = typeof(DateTime?).GetMethod("Between");
    Expression<Func<MyObject, DateTime?>> from = x => x.FromValue as DateTime?;
    Expression<Func<MyObject, DateTime?>> to = x => x.ToValue as DateTime?;
    var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(expression, method, from, to);
    data.ReportExpr = methodCallExpression;
    return data;
}
```

Comment: So you just want to execute `expression` and then return an expression containing that returned value?

Comment: I'm a little new with expressions, but wouldn't executing it at this point lock in the current values of `FromValue` and `ToValue` to where they would not be evaluated later when `ReportExpr` is invoked?

Comment: If all you want is to delay evaluation until some point in the future, you don't really need an expression for that. You can simply assign a delegate and then invoke it at some point in the future (and they are miles easier to work with than Expressions). Is that what you're looking for? Otherwise, you're stuck using `Expression.Lambda()` to construct an expression, and this method does not seem to be inspecting the expression at all for values.

Comment: Tell us more about what you want to achieve. What scenario would this solve?

Comment: I would love to use delegates instead as I'm much more comfortable with them, but unfortunately this is being used to dynamically construct queries at a higher level so I think I'm stuck with Expressions in this case.

Comment: So you want to go from `(Customer c) => c.SomeDateTime` to `(Customer c) => Between(c.SomeDateTime, a, b)`. Correct?

Comment: To give you an idea of what a "MyObjectData" does: it is a vm that contains filtering data for the client to use to create dynamic reports. The view contains a list of like 100 of these different parameters that the client can filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to go from `(Customer c) => c.SomeDateTime` to `(Customer c) => Between(c.SomeDateTime, a, b)`. Look at the sample expressions in the debugger and see how they are structured.

The expression does not contain constants. It contains a parameter `c`. We can reuse the parameter:

```
var cParam = expression.Parameters[0];
```

Next we isolate `c.SomeDateTime`;

```
var memberAccess = expression.Body;
```

Next we construct the new body:

```
Expression.Call(
    "Between",
    memberAccess,
    Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now),
    Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now));
```

Next comes the new lambda:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(cParam, body);
```

Even if I forgot something you'll be able to figure it out now.